Numpy for loop vectorization - points, triangles, area, volume calculation
I have two numpy arrays - one containing coordinates of 3D points and the second with triangles composed from those points. I need to calculate top surface 2D area and volume of this triangles (tetrahedrons?) with base height of the lowest point.
Minimal working example of what I got. It work OK, but is slow.
import numpy as np


pts = np.array([[744, 547, 695], [784, 511, 653], [779, 546, 746], [784, 489, 645], [834, 423, 614], [619, 541, 598]])
trs = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 0], [5, 0, 1]])
h_min = np.min(pts[:, 2])
print(f"H min : {h_min} m", )


a = 0
v = 0
for tr in trs:
    p1, p2, p3 = tr
    x1, y1, z1 = pts[p1]
    x2, y2, z2 = pts[p2]
    x3, y3, z3 = pts[p3]
    area2d = abs(0.5 * (((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1)) - ((x3 - x1) * (y2 - y1))))
    h_mean = (z1 + z2 + z3) / 3 - h_min
    v_tr = area2d * h_mean
    a += area2d
    v += v_tr

print(f"AREA  : {a} m2")
print(f"VOLUME: {v} m3")

The problem is that really those arrays contains millions of points and triangles and this is calculating way too long. I have found method called numpy vectorization, but have no idea how to make it work in my case. Can anyone explain to me if it is even possible? Fast volume calculation is a must. Area - would be great. Thank you!

take a look at numba package. All you need is create function out of your code and add numba decorator to it. Really worth to learn and will work here for sure.

Thank you! I'll definitely take also a look at numba :D

You could use vectorized operations. Way efficient compared to the method you have
[x1, x2, x3], [y1,y2,y3], [z1,z2,z3] = pts[trs].T
area2d = abs(0.5 * (((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1)) - ((x3 - x1) * (y2 - y1))))
a = area2d.sum()
v = area2d @ ( (z1 + z2 + z3) / 3 - h_min)
print(f"AREA  : {a} m2")
print(f"VOLUME: {v} m3")

